# Master Page and Programming Languages

Tags: asp.net, .net, master-pages

I'm working on a joint project and right now we are using a Master Page in VB.  Problem that I'm running in to is I have no experience in coding with VB.  I have been routinely coding in C#, C++, and others in this branch of syntax.  Is it possible to have a Master Page in VB and then have a content page in c#?  I'm not sure if it will directly inherit the language or not.

Comment: Not at the time I posted. I wanted to check before I wrote the code and caused any grief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix C# and VB in the same project only if you are working with a Website project. If it's a web application you need to have a common library which will have your Masterpage Class which can be compiled in a different language.

Here are a few questions which you might find helpful:

1. [How to store an ASP.NET master page
   in a common library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246917/29555)
2. [Difference between 'Web Site' and 'Project' in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590501/difference-between-web-site-and-project-in-visual-studio)

All said. My recommendation would be to take the hit and learn the VB syntax. I know it's very verbose and not pleasant but otherwise you'll have a mix of 2 languages in the project which will make it more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you wouldn't be able to do this, after all the `Page` declaration is only pointing to a `.master` file and you define the language of the page in the header too.

`<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="MySite.Master" %>`

Comment: Thanks.  Just wasn't sure that it was possible but I guess it's no different than a simple script.